# Java generics type binding. Why isn't this compiling?

Tags: java, generics

Given this generic function:

```
<T> List<T> function() { return null; }
```

Why does this compile

```
List<String> l = function();
```

While **this does not**?

```
List<String> l = (List<String>) function();
```

Comment: What is the compiler error that is returned when compiling?

Comment: Cannot cast from List<Object> to List<String>.

Comment: similar issue here with ternary conditional http://stackoverflow.com/q/6535144/731620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like type inference happens after the cast is attempted (by the compiler).

The type of the expression is determined by the left side of the expression, which is not yet "parsed" when the cast is attempted. And the cast itself fails because, with not-yet-inferred type, the result (of the method invocation) is of type `List<Object>`

Section [15.12.2.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#341287) of the JLS indicates that type inference happens last.

Comment: yes, I know, see my comments on aioobe's answer, and his links (which point to the cache)

Answer (score 8):

Because when you do a cast like this:

```
(List<String>) function()
```

the compiler can't infer the type parameter for the `function()` call, and falls back on binding `T` to `Object`.

While in

```
List<String> l = function();
```

it *can* infer the correct type for `T`.

Note that you *may* cast if you circumvent the job of the type inference by explicitly providing the type:

```
import java.util.List;

class Test {
    public static <T> List<T> function() { return null; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = (List<String>) Test.<String>function();
        //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

---

I don't know the exact type inferencing rules for generic parameters. They are however specified in [JLS Section 15.12.2.7](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aQtJydubY1xMJ%3ajava.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html+http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html%23341287&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu&source=www.google.com).

Comment: It seems so, but why is the compiler unable to bind T in the second case?

Comment: I have no idea, but I'd be interested in the answer as well. The JLS (section 15.12.2.7) isn't very intuitive here.

Comment: the Oracle site site is now down btw (incl. JLS), I had to look through the caches..to arrive to the same section that you did :)

Comment: Well, if you (or any other) could give a *concise **"why"*** of this behaviour, i would be glad to accept the answer.

Comment: @Bozho, which is why my current *link* points to a cached version.

Comment: @edutesoy I tried to figure out why it happens like that. Why it is defined like that, I don't think anyone can tell. My guess is that they just added type inference as the last step

Comment: @Bozho, I think it has it's reasons. Type inference is an intricate process, and the expression to the right of a "cast-operator" can probably be just about anything from the type inferers perspective.

Comment: I am looking for exacly how this intricate proccess acts in this case. IMHO it is not still answered.

Comment: Just a tip, the reason adduced here is more a description of what happens, than a reason to *why does it happen*. The reason should be compatible with this scenario (which compiles): `public T f() { return null; }` and then `String s = (String) f();`

Answer (score 1):

The first one uses type inference, using the type of the variable the result is assigned to.

In the second one, the result of the call is not assigned to anything (before the cast is done), so the most generic type is returned (`List<Object>`), and a `List<Object>` can't be cast to a `List<String>`.

Comment: Why doesn't the type inference happen in the second case?

Comment: Because the result of the expression "function()" is not assigned to a variable. It's cast, and the result of the cast is assigned to a variable.

Comment: Your explanation is not enought for me, because you don't need to assign it to a variable, since you can just invoke function(); (without any assignation)...

Comment: Type inference is precisely the action of assigning a generic type to the result of an expression based on the type of the variable to which this result is assigned. Without assignment to a variable, there can't be any type inference, and that's the point : the result of the second function() expression is not assigned to a variable: it's cast. So there can't be type inference in this case, whereas there is one in the first case.

Comment: Upvote because i think you are in the good direction, but it is not complete since it still happens with "return" statements (not only assignments to variables). This said, I am not going to accept it as an answer since I don't think this is the precise explanation (that drives this specific behavior but also others like the "return" scenario). I mean, **"because you assign a variable"** is not the real "why" for me (I invite you to edit or make a new answer :)

Comment: I answered your question : why does the first case compile while the second doesn't. The fact that other kinds of statements, that you didn't mention in your question, happen to compile as well doesn't make my answer incorrect or incomplete : there is type inference in the first one and not in the second.

Comment: Because the expert group who designed Java decided that there should be type inference when the result of a method call is assigned to a variable, but that there shouldn't be when the result of a method call is cast to a type and then assigned to a variable. They also decided to forbid expressions like int i = "2", although they could have decided to automatically convert the string into an integer. That's how it is.

Comment: The reason of *forbiding expresions like i="2"* is that java is type-safe and you cannot assign to a variable a value of another type. Anyway, if your answer is "*Because the expert group who designed Java decided that there should be type inference when the result of a method call is assigned to a variable, but that there shouldn't be when the result of a method call is cast to a type and then assigned to a variable*" then it **fails** in this scenario: `public T f() { return null; }` and then `String s = (String) f();` because this compiles smoothly and it shouldn't according to your reason.

Comment: No it doesn't fail. You have no compile error in this case because f() evaluates to an Object, and an Object can be cast to a String : Object is a superclass of String. Your second case doesn't compile bacause, as the error message says, a List<Object> can't be cast to a List<String>, and that's because a List<Object> is not a superclass of List<String>. They're two different types with no inheritance relationship. Read http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ102

Comment: Yes, you are right, if i could i would upvote you again, but I still think that your answer doesn't really explain the behaviour, but describes it, I find more explicit this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535749/java-generics-type-binding-why-isnt-this-compiling/6541712#6541712, although not still complete. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because javac needs to infer T, but T does not appear in argument types.

```
static<T> T foo(){ .. }

foo(); // T=?
```

Only in 2 cases, javac can infer T from the context

```
String s = foo(); // #1: assignment

String bar(){
    return foo(); // #2: return
```

In other cases, javac won't, and T is simply inferred as Object

Comment: +1, good answer, but i would like to go deeper, why is java unable to infer T when there is a cast? It could infer also the type because it has all the information, isn't it? Why is the type inference not applied to "castings"? I suspect that it has something to do with the way "castings" are resolved and the fact that this compiles: `"a".toString()` whereas this doesnt `(String)"a".toString()`. You can just edit your answer if you want to, so i can accept it.

Comment: Using cast to coerce type inference, is not syntactically better than just specifying the type: `Test.<String>function()`. Therefore there is no compelling reason to do that. In general, the meaning of a bigger expression depends on smaller expressions composing it; if the meaning of a smaller expression also depends on the meaning of the bigger expression, we are in a very messy situation.

Comment: I must say I'm also curious about this. To me it almost seems even *easier* to deduce that the desired binding for `T` is `String`, in the situation of a cast, than in situation of an assignment.

Comment: Casting is more complicated. For example, you can cast a `List` to almost anything, say, a `Thread`. But you can't assign a `List` to a `Thread` variable. Suppose static type of `t` is `T`. With an assignment `S s = t` it is quite clear that `T` must be a subtype of `S`, that constraint can be used for type inference. With a cast `(S)t`, we cannot assume that `T` is a subtype of `S`; actually most times `T` is a super type of `S` (that's why we need the cast), so we can't establish a constraint between `T` and `S` for type inference.

Comment: You may attempt to say that it's simple to add a few more rules to make it work. Nobody will hold such optimism if he just browsed Java language spec. It is going to be an **extremely** hard work, beyond the bold font can express. It can be justified only by extreme benefit. In this example, the benefit is almost zero. Specifying `T` is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

`List<String>` doesn't extend `List<Object>`. So You can't cast it.

You can specify T in next way

```
 List<String> l = this.<String>function();
```

Comment: But `List<String> l = function();` *does* compile, so I see no need for that.

Comment: @aioobe we dont need casting either. As I understand this question is not about how to.

Answer (score 0):

That's because compiler can't infer the parameterized type of the method `function()`, so it binds `T` to `Object`. You can't cast `List<Object>` to `List<String>`.

Comment: Yes, but "why" doesn't it binds T in the second case? the compiler has the information.

Comment: That's because you're not explicitly typecasting, so it'll try to cast it at runtime.

Comment: But in the first statement i don't cast it explicitly either.

Comment: Just for completeness, your statement *"because you're not explicitly typecasting, so it'll try to cast it at runtime"* does it mean that the cast is just applied at run-time? because this is not compatible with this code not compiling: `int i = (int)"1";` the compiler knows that the 2 types are not automatically castable.

Comment: @edutesoy, that's because the compiler does compile-time casting and it knows it can't cast a String object to a primitive int type. For your case, the compiler knows it's returning a list but doesn't know what parameterized type to infer (as you're not typecasting it yourself). It therefore removes the parameterized type to `List` and when you'll do for e.g. `String s = function().get(0)` to see if the object is castable to the type of variable `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not exact.

```
List<String> m = (List<String>)function();
```

produces *warning* "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List" that is correct because all casts to generic types are unsafe.

Comment: For me it produces an error: *`Cannot cast from List<Object> to List<String>`*